# Cypress: is there a way to use filter with a regex?

Tags: filter, cypress, contains

[image: Click here to view the html]

With the html above, I need to get the 3rd `mfc-tree-item` based on the `mfc-text-type` text of the second `mfc-tree-item`, in other words, I need to click on the `mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id='fma-tree-nav-headcount-planning-component']` that is within the `mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id='fma-tree-nav-scenario']` which mfc-text-type's text equal to "Baseline" (contains is not enough). So I was thinking I could use a regex with ^ at the beginning and $ at the end of Baseline, but not sure if that's even supported. Any idea?

```
scenarioName = 'Baseline'
cy.get('mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id="fma-tree-nav-scenario"]')
  .filter(':contains("^"' + scenarioName + '"$", "g")')
  .find(mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id='fma-tree-nav-headcount-planning-component'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a regex with text from a variable, you would need to build it with a RexExp object.

```js
const scenarioName = 'Baseline'
const regex = new RegExp(scenarioName)
cy.contains('mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id="fma-tree-nav-scenario"]', regex)
  .find('mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id="fma-tree-nav-headcount-planning-component"]')
  .should('have.attr', 'icon-color', 'Moonstone')
```

But you can't use `^` and `$` to denote beginning and end of string, because the text of the top element includes all the text of it's children plus white-space and new lines (text nodes).

You could try strengthening the regex, but it would be time consuming and give you a fragile test.

Instead, try going directly to the element with the text, which allows a strong regex, and traverse up the tree to it's ancestor

```js
const scenarioName = 'Baseline'
const regex2 = new RegExp(`^${scenarioName}$`)
cy.contains('mfc-text-type', regex2)
  .parents('mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id="fma-tree-nav-scenario"]')
  .find('mfc-tree-item[data-qa-id="fma-tree-nav-headcount-planning-component"]')
  .should('have.attr', 'icon-color', 'Moonstone')
```